# How to know the lowest value that is not in a group of numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I have a group of numbers 0 to 9 => {0 .. 9}, but another group that represent each amount of {0 .. 9} we have, for example:

```
0 => 1
1 => 2
2 => 3
3 => 4
4 => 5
5 => 6
6 => 7
7 => 8
8 => 9
9 => 1
```

The lowest value that we cannot represent with those groups is **99**. They are digits to represent a number, for example if we only have:

```
2 => 2
7 => 1
```

The lowest value should be **0** or **1**, and the possibilities are, **2**, **7**, **22**, **27**, **72**, **227**, **272**, **722**.

I am doing an algorithym in `java` to calculate the lowest value that we cannot represent, but I even do not very well how to do it, and I need a little or big help.

Thanks.

Comment: little or big help is that you code something and come to this place with that code

Comment: it is still a bit wage! can you explain more? your inputs meaning how many of those digits we have? so 8=>9 means we have 9, eights ?

Comment: @Khashayar The OP is unclear, but I think that's it.

Comment: Yes, sorry if I can't explain it better, a friend told me like that and I tried to understand it better, but he gave me that example and that's what I understood, so yes. 8=>9 means we will have 9 digits of number eight

Comment: @niiraj874u the code is not relevant at the moment, because I need to understand what is going about to get the lowest value, then translate into `java` will be easy

Comment: @ReCaptcha as far I understand 77 can be represented because we have more than one digits of number sever, but for example, we only have one number nine, so, 99 is imposible to represent, but why so? the theorical reason...

Comment: It is actually understandable :)

Comment: @rokimoki I just realised that 2 can appear maximum 2 times and 7 maximum 1 time, so 77 shouldn't appear according to that logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decompose your problem.

#### Global algorithm

IMO, you should start at `n = 0`, and go up. For each value of `n`, check if the sequence of digits needed to represent it is allowed. As soon as you can't, `n` is your answer.

#### Smaller part

The new problem is to verify if the sequence of digits for a given number is allowed. That does not seem very difficult. You seem to deal with base 10 numbers only I guess:

- decompose your number in base 10 digits
- count the number of occurrences of each digit in your number
- compare with the quantity available of that digit

  - if there are not enough, you're done, the number can't be represented
  - if there are enough, keep going with the other digits

---

Example implementation of the main algo. The argument `nbAllowed` would be a 10-sized array containing the quantity available of each digit. Ex: `nbAllowed[2]` is the number of times that the digit '2' is allowed to be used.

```
public static int smallestNonRepresentable(int[] nbAllowed) {
    int n=0;
    while (isRepresentable(n, nbAllowed)) {
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Example implementation of the subroutine. This methods returns whether `n` is representable depending on the quantity available for each digit.

```
private static boolean isRepresentable(int n, int[] nbAllowed) {
    int[] digitCount = getDigitCount(n);

    // check if each digit is available enough times
    for (int d = 0; d < nbAllowed.length; d++) {
        if (nbAllowed[d] < digitCount[d]) {
            return false; // not enough d digits to represent n
        }
    }
    return true; // enough of all digits
}
```

Example implementation of how to count the number of occurrences of each digit in a number n. This method returns a 10-sized array containing the number of occurrences of each digit in n. Ex: `digitCount[2]` is the number of times that the digit '2' appears in the decimal representation of `n`.

```
private static int[] getDigitCount(int n) {
    int[] digitCount = new int[10]; // 10 distinct digits
    Arrays.fill(digitCount, 0); // start at 0 occurrence for each digit

    // special case 0
    if (n == 0) {
        digitCount[0] = 1; // 1 occurrence for digit '0'
        return digitCount;
    }

    // fill digitCount with the number of occurrences of each digit in n
    int digit;
    while(n > 0) {
        digit = n % 10; // current last digit of n
        digitCount[digit]++; // increments the number of occurrences for that digit
        n /= 10; // shifts the decimal number n to the right (last digit disappears)
    }
    return digitCount;
}
```

Comment: That was what I thought to do, but for every `n` I have to check from the first combination possible to the <= `n`, for `n + 1` the same, is that right?

Comment: @rokimoki No you don't need to check all possible combinations, just count the occurrences of each digit in `n`, and see if you have enough in your "authorized number" for each digit. I rephrased my answer so that it's clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and code sample, I will try to understand it before implement, it seems very simple the solution, but I am not clever enough for this kind of 'games'...

Comment: @rokimoki I explained some parts of the code in comments, to make things clearer.

Comment: @rokimoki Sorry I should have left you figure the code out, so that you understand better. Reading a solution is never a good way of learning. My bad, I couldn't resist the urge ^^

Comment: Don't worry because is not about programming, just thinking, learning this kind of things in the future you can use the mechanics to solve new problems, so in this case I think the solution is usefull to learn.

Comment: Ok, then my advice would be to decompose. First, think globally. What would you do if you had to do it yourself? Find the general idea, and assume you have big basic blocks to build your algorithm. Then, refine the basic blocks. That's how you end up with the kind of methods hierarchy that I provided.

Comment: Your solution is brute force. In case you have a large amount of digits available, the algorithm does not scale at all. Why did you picked an `int` to represent the target number and not a `String`, which would widen the numbers to process?

Comment: @Harmlezz Fair point. This is just a suggestion, I used `int` because it is simple to understand, and adds very little overhead. It might work like a charm depending on the use case of the OP (the example shows very small values). If it needs to work on large numbers, then the use of Strings might be suitable indeed (actually I had mentioned it in previous versions of my answer, but I removed it for the purpose of simplicity).

Comment: There is a case when all amount of digits are 0

Comment: @rokimoki Then the program should return 0. I think it does, doesn't it?

Comment: Should return 1, because is the lowest value that cannot be prompted, but, solved initializing 'n' to 1

Comment: @rokimoki If you don't have any digit, then you can't even create the value '0'. So 0 is the lowest natural integer that cannot be represented by your empty set of digits.

Comment: Yes I understand but logically if you have 0 as any value, the minimum legit value always is 1, so we cannot represent 1, so 1 is the solution.

Comment: @rokimoki I don't understand "*if you have 0 as any value*". IMO, 0 is the first value to consider, and you don't have any digits to represent it, that's all you need to conclude that 0 is the answer in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved by not applying brute-force. There are four cases to distinguish in the given order, which means if we evaluate case 3, case 1 and 2 did not apply:

1. There is at least one digit with an amount of **zero**: then the smallest of those digits is not representable.
2. The set of digits with the smallest available amount does not contain the digit **zero**: now we know the amount is greater than zero and hence repeating the smallest of those digits one more time than available digits is the smallest non representable number.
3. The set of digits with the smallest available amount has a size of **one**: now we know it has to be the digit **zero** having an amount greater than zero. And we know the next greater digit, the **one** is available, due to passed through **case 1**. Hence the number composed of a leading *1* followed by amount many **zeros** is the smallest non representable number.
4. We know the set of digits with the smallest available amount contains the digit **zero** and at least one more digit: hence repeating the second smallest digit of this set one more time than available digits is the smallest non representable number.

Expressed in terms of a Java program the main algorithm looks like this:

```
private static final List<Integer> DIGIT_POOL =
    Arrays.asList(2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> amountToDigits = mapToDigits(DIGIT_POOL);
    String number;
    int amount = amountToDigits.keySet().iterator().next();
    List<Integer> digits = amountToDigits.get(amount);
    if (amount == 0) {
        number = number(digits.get(0), 1);
    } else if (!digits.contains(0)) {
        number = number(digits.get(0), amount + 1);
    } else if (digits.size() == 1) {
        number = paddedWithZero(1, amount + 2);
    } else {
        number = number(digits.get(1), amount + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(number);
}

private static SortedMap<Integer, List<Integer>> mapToDigits(List<Integer> digitAmounts) {
    SortedMap<Integer, List<Integer>> amountToDigits = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int digit = 0; digit <= 9; digit++) {
        int amount = digitAmounts.get(digit);
        List<Integer> digits = amountToDigits.get(amount);
        if (digits == null) {
            digits = new ArrayList<>();
            amountToDigits.put(amount, digits);
        }
        digits.add(digit);
    }
    return amountToDigits;
}
```

Constructing the resulting non representable number requires the following helper methods:

```
private static String paddedWithZero(Integer digit, int length) {
    char[] letters = letters(0, length);
    letters[0] = digit.toString().charAt(0);
    return new String(letters);
}

private static String number(Integer digit, int length) {
    return new String(letters(digit, length));
}

private static char[] letters(Integer digit, int length) {
    char[] letters = new char[length];
    Arrays.fill(letters, digit.toString().charAt(0));
    return letters;
}
```

The total complexity of the algorithms is the sum of:

- mapping **n** digits to their amounts: **O(n)**
- distinguishing between **four** cases: **O(1)**
- constructing a number of lenght **m + 1**, where **m** is the smallest amount of available digits: **O(m)**

Hence the total complexity is **O(max(n, m))** which is linear. This solution works pretty fast for very large amounts (1k and greater) of given digits.

Comment: I like that solution, but we consider a case that all amounts of digits could be zero, and I think is very complex, but I like.

Comment: This solution covers all cases, even if all digits have an amount of 0. But the advantage of this solution is that it is lightning fast for very large numbers. Consider a number having 1000 digits. My solution is able to produce an answer in less than a second and it is not restricted to `int` or `long` values. Your favorite solution will process forever if the amount of digits is greater than 20 and above i guess. Please try it and post me a feedback when the other algorithm does take more than 5 minutes to find the smallest number given, all digits have the same amount.

Comment: @Harmlezz +1 for taking the time to look for a non brute force solution. I would indeed choose such a solution (or similar) if I had to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you're going from the lowest point, it's usually prudent to start at `0`. So we'll need some sort of loop, and because we don't know how many times we'll look, we'll implement a `while` loop.

```
boolean numberFound = false;

while(!numberFound) {
    // Loops while a number has not been found.
}
```

We also need to keep track of our current number, so we'll declare a pointer `p`.

```
int p = 0;

boolean numberFound = false;

while(!numberFound) {
}
```

Now, let's assume you've got all these values in an array. So `1` is in position `0`, `2` is in position `1` etc. You need to get the first value of `p`. Now, for any value of `p` between `9` and `0` inclusively, we can just grab the number of occurrences, so we do something like:

```
if(p <= 9 && p >= 0) {
     // Get the number of occurrences.
     int numberOfDigits = digits[p] // Digits is your array as described above.

     if(numberOfDigits == 0) {
         // You only need one digit to represent this number.
         // If you don't have one digit, you've just found a number that works.
         numberFound = true;
     }
}
```

Next, you'll need to deal with numbers larger than `9`. Because this has more than one digit, you'll need to do this in stages:

- First, convert the `Integer` into a `String`.
- Next, cycle through each character in that String.
- Parse that character back to an integer, and grab the value from the array.
- Get the number of times that character occurs in a string.
- If the value in the array is less than the number of times that value occurs..

  - You've found a number.
- Else, keep looping.

Good luck with the last part of the solution. As a general rule, when it looks like someone hasn't made much of an effort with a problem, I don't provide the entire solution.

Comment: I think I can understand your explanation, by the way, very well explained, but check @Joffrey explanation, the solution is different than yours and probabble simpler, what do you think? because we don't use any `Integer` into `String` but finally we are checking occurrences

Comment: Yes, it is following the same principle but using the `%` operator is a clever trick to avoid the `String` cast. I'd go with his answer, because it will require less processing time. But I'll leave mine here because it simply offers another solution. The only thing I would say, is that there is no need to create an `array` containing the count of every value occurrence; this can just be calculated inside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is the same as Joffrey's algo.

Write a method like:

```
public boolean checkIfInGroup(int value) {
    ...
}
```

then you can create a loop in your outer method:

```
int n=0;
while (checkIfInGroup(n)) {
    n++;
}
return n;
```

The challenge would be how to optimize the checkIfInGroup() method.

Answer (score -2):

If I understood you correctly, you have one Array with numbers from 0 - 9 and another one with the same numbers in a different order. You want to know, which number is the one below the smallest displayable. So, if I understood you correctly, it should always be -1, because, if you have numbers from 0 - 9, 0 is the lowest displayable number, so -1 is the one beneath that. Could I help?

Comment: No because in my example is clearly **99** because is inside the range we can represent, but not in the group of numbers available

Comment: Ok, I understand you more clearly now. But why 99? Isn't 99 the highest number? And what about the second example? Why 1 <b>or</b> 0? Shouldn't it be only 1?

Comment: The 0 or 1 just becuase I don't know if 0 is consider as the lowest or just 1, in the main example is 99, because only have one number 9 digit, and 99 is two nine digits, and is the lowest which cannot be represented